# Как вызвать функцию при нажатии на раскрытие узла TreeView?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Как вызвать функцию при нажатии на раскрытие узла TreeView ?

Есть TreeViewItem.Expanded но оно постоянно запускается много раз, а нужно только когда нажмут на открытие узла.

TreeViewItem.Expanded запускается много раз при открытии программы, при добавлении новых веток.

Возможно потому что при открытии устанавливается значение

```
<Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded}"/>
```

Comment: А в чем проблема? Добавьте в метод что-то вроде `if (newValue == oldValue) return;` и все.